# NotImplementError while inspecting PyTorch nn model

Tags: python, exception, pytorch

I'm trying to inspect the model(PyTorch) but it shows the following error!

```
Unable to display children:Error resolving variables Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1208, in do_it
    xml.write(pydevd_xml.var_to_xml(val, k, evaluate_full_value=evaluate_full_value))
  File "D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_xml.py", line 369, in var_to_xml
    elif hasattr(v, "__len__") and not is_string(v):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\pt37\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\backends\backend.py", line 10, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

What's the `__getattr__` method and how do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

[`__getattr__`](https://blog.rmotr.com/python-magic-methods-and-getattr-75cf896b3f88), when implemented, allows you to inspect calls for non-existing attributes in your class.
I'm not sure your problem lies in the implementation of `__getattrt__`, though. It seems like you are trying to parse an XML to get your model and something went wrong during the parsing process.